# Would an electric light help an Aloe vera plant?

Tags: aloe, light, grow-lamp

I have an *Aloe vera* plant in a large pot. It was doing well but when I moved homes I can't keep it as much sun light. It's getting a bit droopy and has brown parts. I'm wondering if a lamp would help it? Is there a specific type of light, or wavelength, that *Aloe vera* plants like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aloe vera normally grows in high direct sunlight, very warm and fairly dry conditions. It has responded by leaning towards a method of growing that stores water in leaves and roots and the firm leaf surface controls for water loss. You may be able to provide supplemental lighting but you would need a lot to replace direct sunlight for many hours in a day. An alternative might be to think of a friend who has a high light window and offer the plant as a gift. Explain the situation, and each time you visit you get to see both your old friends.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience I would say you might be over watering your plant. Given your plant is in a large pot and it was in a well lit area before, if you did not cut back on the watering you probably gave it too much. Watering should be adjusted to the amount of light a plant receives.

Mine is 1 meter away of a North facing window, which is a low light spot plus it is winter now so it is even more low light spot. The plant itself has around 20 cm long leaves and some pups. I have it in a very small, 5-6 cm terracotta pot in a very well aerated soil mix and I am watering it only every 3 weeks.

So in theory more light could help, but I would adjust the watering first.